# Actions on Google: Alpha Tester

Tags: actions-on-google

I read the guide on Actions on Google, concerning the [publication of an alpha version](https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments)

3 days ago, I have filled out the form

[image]

However, when I share [the test link](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000c819248b30), this error appears:

At the moment it is not possible to find what you are looking for. Try later.

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is a Google bug

I did a further test:
I opened the link on an Android device

In this case I display a form to publish my review,
but anyway I can not test the application

Can you help me ?

Comment: In the console > deploy > release what does it say under current releases and under alpha (not manage alpha testers), can you share screenshots and update the question please?

Answer (score 2):

You should not open this in the browser, instead choose the Google Assistant app on your mobile and open this page from mobile device. Then scroll down to the middle of the directory page/opt-in link you have been given and enable yourself as an Alpha Tester (you will see this button only if you have been whitelisted by the app owner/developer) and continue testing your app on mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get this page for several hours after enabling alpha testing.  After some time it switched to showing me the action directory listing for our app.

Once the page is active and you can see the directory listing you'll need to open the link *on your mobile phone!* This is mentioned in really small and un-emphasized copy under the link.  Also, it's not immediately obvious as the opt in link will most likely be below the bottom edge of your phone screen.  You'll have to scroll down to opt-in to alpha testing.  Once you enable alpha-testing you should immediately have access to the action.

Answer (score -1):

even i faced the issue , but you can alpha test by switching your account like in google assistant change your default account like the account you used for development.
this might help , thank you

Comment: I do not understand. According to your suggestion should I provide my users to the 20 users who have to test the application?